# Using Angular, my API has serval pages of objects and i want to call all of them and join all of them into one object

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am working with the http://swapi.co/ API and Angular.
I am trying to display all the characters on one page. 
the problem is that the character list is separated by different pages for ex: http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=1, http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2, etc..

The response has a next and previous object in the JSON response for ex:

```
"next": "http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=3", 
"previous": "http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=1", 
"results": [
    {
        "name": "Anakin Skywalker", 
        "height": "188", 
        "mass": "84",
```

I would like to string these pages together in one object so that I can display all characters under one page and I am assuming the logic will include me checking when the "next" object is == to null then stop incrementing the page number and making a request to the API. I am very new to Angular as well as REST and would appreciate any help given, thanks.
I currently have my code working so that when the user hits the next button it makes a new request and increments my value variable by one which is returned in the function with that new value. This is not what I want to do it was more of a learning test just to see if I could.
Here is my Controller.js:

```
/*global angular:true */
angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).
/* characters controller */
controller('charactersController', function($scope, starwarsAPIservice) {
$scope.nameFilter = null;
$scope.characterList = [];
$scope.searchFilter = function (character) {
    var re = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
    return !$scope.nameFilter || re.test(character.name) || re.test(character.gender);
};

starwarsAPIservice.getCharacters().success(function (response) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    console.log($scope.loading);
    var check = response;
    $scope.characterList = response.results;
    return check;
}).then(function successCallback(check){
    var val = 1;
    if(check.next !== null){
      val++;
      console.log('More pages to be loaded');
    }else {
      console.log('No More pages to be loaded');
    }
}).finally(function(){
  $scope.loading = false;
  console.log($scope.loading);
});
var value = 1;
$('.previouspage').addClass('hidden');
$('button').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('nextpage')){
    value++;
    if(value <= 1){
      $('.previouspage').addClass('hidden');
    }else{
      $('.previouspage').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    console.log(value);
    starwarsAPIservice.getChar(value).success(function (response) {
        $scope.characterList = response.results;
    });
      }
      else {
        value--;
        if(value <= 1){
          $('.previouspage').addClass('hidden');
        }else{
          $('.previouspage').removeClass('hidden');
        }
        console.log(value);
        starwarsAPIservice.getChar(value).success(function (response) {
        $scope.characterList = response.results;
    });
  }
});


}).

  /* character controller */
   controller('characterController', function($scope, $routeParams, starwarsAPIservice) {
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
$scope.character = [];
$scope.planet = [];

starwarsAPIservice.getCharacterDetails($scope.id).success(function (response) {
    $scope.character = response;
});

starwarsAPIservice.getCharacterPlanet($scope.id).success(function (response) {
    $scope.planet = response;
});

});
```

Here is my service.js file:

```
/*global angular:true */
angular.module('F1FeederApp.services', [])
 .factory('starwarsAPIservice', function($http) {

var ergastAPI = {};

ergastAPI.getCharacters = function(){
    return $http.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/');
};
ergastAPI.getChar = function(value){
    return $http.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/?page='+value+'');
};
ergastAPI.getCharacterDetails = function(id){
    return $http.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/'+id+'/?format=json');
};
ergastAPI.getCharacterPlanet = function(id){
    return $http.get('http://swapi.co/api/planets/'+id+'/?format=json');
};

return ergastAPI;
});
```

Comment: would suggest you first learn how to not use jQuery for your app and learn how to use the data model to manage the view. You already have issues by using events outside of angular updating your scope. Should never be any DOM code in a controller either

Comment: I understand that, can you please look around that mess and give me some insight on how to get around the problem I am having?

Comment: That will be part of my learning process as soon as i figure out how to display all the characters by combing the multiple JSON objects and displaying in one list on the dom.

Comment: The jQuery in the controller will be removed as it was more of a test of can it be done. i also don't want the user to have to select the next button to see more characters.

Comment: will need empty arrays to start with and push data to array each time. In callback check `next` and call same service method again, service method does the check and calls itself again if `next` is available. Controller just binds to the empty array

Comment: thank you for the response, i have a basic idea of what you are asking me to do but i am unable to replicate it properly. Would you mind showing me using the code above?

Comment: I am assuming i will need to move my success callback function inside my service.js file

Comment: yes... controller would just see array, service method would need an extra argument for `nextUrl`'